# I am making a signup page in my flask app but login manager is not defined

Tags: python, flask, web

I am making a flask chatting website and currently, I am trying to create a sign-in/sign-up page but I keep getting this error

```
  File "C:\Users\asadp\OneDrive\Desktop\Website-Codemy\app.py", line 49, in <module>
    @login_manager.user_loader
NameError: name 'login_manager' is not defined
```

**Code**

```
--snip--

lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)

class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Name %r>' % self.id
--snip--
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)

@app.route('/signup', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def signup():
    title = "Signup"

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_name = request.form['name']
        user_password = request.form['password']
        user_email = request.form['email']
        new_user = Friends(name=user_name, password=user_password)

        try:
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.sesssion.commit()

        except:
            return "There was an error"

    else:
        return render_template("signup.html")

--snip--
app.run()
```

Please tell me how to fix it
I am a beginner in flask so I would really appreciate it if you could reply fast
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you haven't defined the variable `login_manager`.

You should be using `@login_manager.user_loader` if you had stored the instance of `LoginManager` in a variable called `login_manager`. But in your example code you are using a variable called `lm`. In order to fix it you should change:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)
```

to

```
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)
```

**Or**, you could change

```
lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
```

to

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

It's up to you.